# Why doesn't this SetBinding ImageSourceProperty Work?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, f#, binding

```
let mtvCapView = Rendering.MTViewerCaptureViewProvider(subRead)
let image = Image()
let imageBinding = Data.Binding("ImageElement")
imageBinding.Source <- mtvCapView
image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, imageBinding)
....
Grid.SetColumn(image, 1) 
grid.Children.Add(image)
```

The MTViewerCaptureViewProvider class exposes an property ImageElement which is set and should work here.  If I:

```
Grid.SetColumn(mtvCapView.ImageElement, 1) 
grid.Children.Add(mtvCapView.ImageElement)
```

This works.  Why does the other not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I look at the variable and property-names, I think you're trying to set an image as the image source of an image:

MTViewerCaptureViewProvider has a property `ImageElement`. If the name is correct , it gives you already an `Image`, not an `ImageSource`. In the binding then your try to bind this image to the ImageSource of your newly created Image.

Maybe there existst a TypeConverter for `Image` to `ImageSource` that is implicitely used, but I don't think so. Try either to use the `Image` itslelf or get the `ImageSource` of the `MTViewerCaptureViewProvider.ImageElement`.

If you work with VisualStudio look in the output-window. Binding exceptions will be shown there.